# What is the best way to integrate angular js app to Rails asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I had an application deployed on two servers : an apache for AngularJS and a Unicorn for Rails 4. Now I want to integrate the Angular app into the Rails one. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The angular app is just a static html application, serve it as such. If you use HTML5 mode, you'll have to additionally add in some url rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kevin B's comment, here's a cool tutorial on using Rails (Rails 4) to build a JSON REST API that interacts with an AngularJS frontend. Link: https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/ GL!